# Page Layout Issues

Tags: html, css, layout

Please let me know why there is lot of white space below the page content and also why horizontal scroll bar is displayed. Attaching link to zip folder below. Unzip and open index.html.
[link text](http://shivanand.in/tmp/Basic_Profile.zip)

Comment: Why not just put the page up "as is" so we can just browse to a link to see it? There's not a lot of advantage in having it locally... we could always grab it if we needed it.

Comment: Having downloaded it, I see there's also a load of unnecessary stuff in there. A single HTML file with a single CSS file would have been much more useful.

Comment: Just add a new fix: simply add overflow: hidden; to your div#container css rule and tell me if this work better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First lead:

The rule `div#content` almost works in IE, and does put extra width in FireFox:

The extra width is applied to your div class "`content`"

```
div#content { margin: 3px 3px 3px 188px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none 
    repeat; min-height: 392px; }
```

within the div class "`container`"

```
div#container { margin: auto; padding: 10px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255) 
   none repeat; position: relative; min-height: 400px; 
   max-width: 100%; min-width: 750px; }
```

horizontal scroll bar is displayed is for the 188px added to the right of the content. Of course, they need to stay: do not remove them.

**add `overflow: hidden`; to your `div#container` css rule**

On a more general note, you may want to follow the ["Progressive Enhancement with CSS"](http://alistapart.com/articles/progressiveenhancementwithcss) best practice, and separate your css rules in several files (up until actual deployment into production, where you may regroup and compress all your css rules into one tight file)

Comment: 188px is added to give space for the left block. If I remove then the content pushes into the left block.

Comment: When I add overflow:auto; it gives another set of scroll bars inside.

Comment: And with overflow:auto; add to both content and container divs, what do you get ? Even if there is still scroll bars, do you see very little extra space as opposed to the current situation ?

Comment: No. Now the space is seen inside the inner scroll.

Answer (score 0):

VonC is right. Add overflow: hidden; to div#container rule.
Line 274 of index.css.

Answer (score 0):

For scroll bar what VonC suggested is correct whereas "lot of white space below the page content " is due to :  'min-height' that you have specified. You can use the attribute "auto" for that instead of specifying pixels

Regarding : "When I add overflow:auto; it gives another set of scroll bars inside. " .. For this add overflow:auto to all the divs you have used

Comment: overflow: hidden fixes the "lot of white space below the page content " issue too